Azure AGIC giving 502 Bad Gateway with AKS
I have configured Azure AKS cluster with kubenet Plugin. after that have created Application Gateway with same resource group and same vnet.
After that I have update route table entry for communication from Application Gateway to AKS Services.

My NSG Group rules

Troubleshoot Error

I am using default health probe. Deploy just nginx app to test connectivity first. All resources in single resource group.

So what are possible ways we have in this flow?
Thanks

make sure the controller is properly deployed and exposed to handle traffic from the App Gateway

To ensure communication between your Application Gateway and AKS, resolving potential 502 error.
You can follow the below steps and cross check with your setup.
Create your application Gateway

and get the below details for setting up your AGIC
az network vnet subnet show


az aks show

Now enable Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) in your AKS
az aks enable-addons \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --name AGIC \
    --addons ingress-appgw \
    --appgw-name myAppGateway \
    --appgw-subnet-id


kubectl get pods -n kube-system


The ingress-appgw pod is running, which means AGIC is properly set up to route traffic between your Application Gateway and services deployed in AKS.
test it by deploying a sample application
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP


Now for this app we will need an ingress to expose it
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80

Now go to the public IP you created for your app gw, you can see your app is deployed.

If you want to troubleshoot your own setup , you can check out these docs from MS

Troubleshooting bad gateway errors in Application Gateway
Enable application gateway ingress controller add-on for an existing AKS cluster with an existing application gateway


I have setup AKS using kubenet plugin.

If that's the case then instead of using ClusterIP for the service, use a service type NodePort or LoadBalancer to expose the service to the App GW in your kubenet setup.
